# c# Ajax IsInAsyncPostBack not working in Chrome, FF or SAFARI - trouble with partial postback

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a standard thumbnail gallery with a carousel to browse through the thumbnails.  I have a set of links, when clicked, loads the thumbnails into the carousel. **In IE, this works awesome and perfect.**  In Chrome, FF and Safari, the partial-postback is not being sensed and the js is not being re-loaded on asyncpostback because the jquery on the page is all broken/not working (ie togglefade not working, click events not firing for hide events, etc)

EDIT: ** On the HTML side, there are 2 update panels, one nested within the other. I added the HTML code which might help. I've stripped out most of the page content and just left the update panels, etc so everyone can get a idea of the html side of things.

HTML

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPnlRedCarpet" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="redCarpetCarousel">
                                    <div class="redCarpet">
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

INSIDE CODE-BEHIND PAGE_LOAD EVENT

```
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
           RegisterClientStartupScript();
        }
```

REGISTER CLIENT START-UP SCRIPT CODE-BEHIND

```
    private void RegisterClientStartupScript()
    {
        string path = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.msCarousel-min.js");
        ScriptManager sManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        if (sManager != null && sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
               this.updtPnlRedCarpet, typeof(string), "include-js",
               path);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updtPnlRedCarpet, this.updtPnlRedCarpet.GetType(), "SliderScript",
               "runTheCarousel();", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updtPnlRedCarpet, this.updtPnlRedCarpet.GetType(), "ClickScript",
                "loadThePage();", true);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("SliderScript", path);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that FF, Chrome and Safari DO NOT like document.ready before javascript functions. Once I removed the document.ready bits, FF, Chrome and Safari were able to find the functions and everything is once again quiet in the universe.